# Amplify Datastore configure

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify

I have React native aplication with amplify, use auth and datastore categories. Is a good way to disable sync in react native app, this is in app.tsx, I wont to disable sync to cloud if user is't paid and when he becom paid it will have sync data.

```
useEffect(() => {
     const checkUser = async () => {
      try {
        const currentUser = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
        const userStatus = currentUser.profile === 'paid' ? 'paid' : 'free';
        if (userStatus === 'paid') {
          DataStore.configure({
            storageAdapter: SQLiteAdapter,
          });
        } else {
          DataStore.configure({
            storageAdapter: SQLiteAdapter,
            syncExpressions: [
              syncExpression(Task, (task: any) => task.id('eq', '')),
              syncExpression(Category, (cat: any) => cat.id('eq', '')),
              syncExpression(GoalItem, (item: any) => item.id('eq', '')),
              syncExpression(Goal, (goal: any) => goal.id('eq', ''))
            ]
          });
        }
        setUser(currentUser);
      } catch (error) {
        setUser(null);
      }
      setIsLoading(false);
    };
    checkUser();
  }, []);
```